# Android orientation and responsive layout

Tags: android

I'm running android 4.4.4 on a 52" touchscreen mounted in portrait orientation. Even when requesting the desktop site to the browser, because of the portrait orientation, I get the responsively scaled version of many sites. I believe that this is related to the system reporting it's orientation as portrait. I have adjusted the resolution in various configurations but still get the scaled display. The zoom and scale settings have been disabled in the browser too.

I can fix this on the sites that I manage programmatically, but I would rather solve the problem on the device since I don't manage all the sites. Is there a way I can forge reported resolution or reported orientation to prevent this behavior? Any other ideas as to how to resolve this? The OS is rooted, so anything goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an experimental API for device orientation, but most developers calculate it from the provided browser properties, so you can't really fake that from your side.

But, I'm not sure if the problem you're running in to is not one of orientation or of the pixel ratio. On most devices the resolution is halved to provide double density displays. This means that even though you might request the full site and be on a screen that could reasonably render 1080 x 1920, because the browser expects to employ pixel doubling, it might only render it as if it were 540 x 960 and the over-sized elements are your screen being, essentially, waaaaaay too big, but proportionally correct.

If you're tethering to a phone you might see if there is a device specific method or app that overcomes this limitation. If you have installed directly on the firmware of a display, I would contact the manufacturer if it is supported.

Best of luck!

Comment: Brushing the cobwebs off this one... The device is actually an i7 in an ultra-compact form factor which is then plugged into the screen via hdmi for video and sound and usb for touch interface. Turns out that by using the default android browser, as opposed to chrome or firefox, resolved most of the display issues.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the 'orientation' is not reported. Just the window size is reported.  You may be experiencing that some browsers will get the desktop layout but then scale up the font size to try to make it more mobile friendly.